# How to run multiple stored procedures using loop inside transaction?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Using Nodejs and https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql

I have multiple stored procedures and want to run asynchronous as the coming iteration depends on the result of before.

```
transaction.begin(async error => {
    try {
        let count = 0;

        transactions.forEach(t => {
            const request = new db.sql.Request(transaction);

            request.execute(t, (error, recordsets) => {
                console.log(error)
                if (recordsets && recordsets.returnValue !== 0) {
                    transaction.rollback();
                    return res.status(422).json([responses[recordsets.returnValue]]);
                }

                if (recordsets && recordsets.returnValue === 0 && transactions.length === count) {
                    transaction.commit(tErr => tErr && next('transaction commit error'));
                    return res.status(200).json([responses[0]]);
                }
            });
            count++;
        });
    } catch (err) {
        transaction.rollback(
            tErr => tErr && done('transaction rollback error')
        );
    }
});
```

Error:

> TransactionError: Can't acquire connection for the request. There is
>   another request in progress.

The `transactions.forEach` each iteration should work for the result of `request.execute` (callback)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if this is it necessary creating a new object like this
`const request = new db.sql.Request(transaction);`

you can do this in two ways, but I think for this, the first option is the one.

1. one makes it async.
   `transactions.forEach(async t => {`
   and
   `await request.execute(t, (error, recordsets) => {`
2. try to write it as a `promise`, and get all the results with `Promise.all()`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#promises
https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#asyncawait

https://jsfiddle.net/reaxdbnz/

Comment: Thanks. I tried this but getting same error. 
Look here: jsfiddle.net/1h7b3xwu/2

Answer (score 1):

The easiest option is to use async await (https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#asyncawait)

Then you can do something like:

```
async function doWork() {
  let count = 0;

  for(const transaction of transactions) {
    const result = await execute(...);
    count++;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time looking into this. I tried this but it gives same error. Since it's in loop, it does not wait for execution but does work if it's outside the loop.